# How to use multiple SSL Keys when using two different git servers?

Tags: git, ssl-certificate, gitblit

I've currently set-up a private install of [GitBlit](http://gitblit.com) on a private server for use on private repos.

I also have to use a company install of GitBlit for our company projects.

In a perfect world, I would be able to use [ssh](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) (like GitHub does) and configure different ssh keys for each server.

Unfortunately GitBlit has chosen to use SSL and not use SSH. Installing a single SSL cert for git is really simple.

```
git config --global http.sslKey path/to/username.key
```

But in setting the global attribute, it appears as though I can only have a single key. Is the only way around this to override the `GIT_SSL_KEY` in the project, or is there any way to utilize two different SSL keys within the global settings (IE: pointing `http:sslKey` to a `.config` file rather than a `.key` file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure a project differently by dropping the `--global` argument and run it in the folder for the project you want to configure.

For example:

1. Configure company SSL key as the global default key

   ```
   git config --global http.sslKey path/to/company.key
   ```
2. Configure each private repo with your private key

   ```
   cd /my/private/repo
   git config http.sslKey path/to/private.key
   ```

Comment: It's a "one time" operation per repository. If you tend to clone new private repos "a lot", why not just write a clone script that performs the `git clone` and then this config afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the only way around this to override the GIT_SSL_KEY in the project

It is one way, the other being to set a *local* config `http.sslKey` value (i.e. one `http.sslKey` per repo)